# How to send silent notification from server to ios devices?

Tags: python, ios, django, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my python script which sends the fcm notifications to the devices.

It sends priority notifications not silent notifications....
How can I silence them ?

```
def sendGCMToTopiciOS():
    url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'
    headers = {
        'UserAgent': "GCM-Server",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        'Authorization': 'key=' + 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    }

    data = {'title': 'Yugam', 'message': 'Hello Everyone', 'event': '13', 'workshop': '-1',
            'link': 'https://www.google.com'}

    notification = {
        'body': data.get('message'),
        'title': data.get('title')
    }

    values = {

        'to': '/topics/' + 'global',
        'data': data,
        'notification': notification,

         "aps":{
             "content-available":1}

    }

    pipe = requests.post(url=url, json=values, headers=headers)
    return pipe.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a **data-message** you need to skip the `notification` part of the json payload

Comment: Can you add more info why it's not working? Could you try while the app is open but in background?

Answer (score 0):

The 'notification' field will cause iOS 10 to send your notifications to the system, automatically displaying notifications based on the given values. If you're looking for a completely silent notification try:

```
values = {
    'to': '/topics/' + 'global',
    'content_available': true
    'priority': 'high',
    'data': data
}
```

This will be delivered in the background without an alert. The 'content_available' field will also convert to 'content-available':1 after passing through the GCM server for APNS.